# Getting JSON error after filtering data but Page loads fine without filtering

Tags: php, mysql

I have a grid that loads fine until I try to apply a filter then i get the following error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in

```
        // build the query.
        $result = $conn->query($query) or die("SQL Error 1: " . mysqli_error());
        $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `found_rows`;";
        $rows = $conn->query($sql);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows);
        $total_rows = $rows['found_rows'];

        $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS profile_pic_url, username, full_name, biography, edge_followed_by, edge_follow FROM owner ORDER BY edge_followed_by DESC LIMIT $start, $total_rows".$where." ";
    }
}

$result = $conn->query($query) ;
$sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `found_rows`;";
$rows = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows);
$total_rows = $rows['found_rows'];
$orders = null;
// get data and store in a json array
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: Where do you define `$where`? `$result` is probably `false` because your query is invalid. Try using [mysqli_error](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed information on what's wrong with your query

Comment: Further, please use a better title. This has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

@kryptur - this is where $where is defined

// filter data.

```
if (isset($_GET['filterscount']))
{
    $filterscount = $_GET['filterscount'];

    if ($filterscount > 0)
    {
        $where = " WHERE (";
        $tmpdatafield = "";
        $tmpfilteroperator = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < $filterscount; $i++)
            {
            // get the filter's value.
            $filtervalue = $_GET["filtervalue" . $i];
            // get the filter's condition.
            $filtercondition = $_GET["filtercondition" . $i];
            // get the filter's column.
            $filterdatafield = $_GET["filterdatafield" . $i];
            // get the filter's operator.
            $filteroperator = $_GET["filteroperator" . $i];

            if ($tmpdatafield == "")
            {
                $tmpdatafield = $filterdatafield;
            }
            else if ($tmpdatafield <> $filterdatafield)
            {
                $where .= ")AND(";
            }
            else if ($tmpdatafield == $filterdatafield)
            {
                if ($tmpfilteroperator == 0)
                {
                    $where .= " AND ";
                }
                else $where .= " OR ";
            }

            // build the "WHERE" clause depending on the filter's condition, value and datafield.
            switch($filtercondition)
            {
                case "CONTAINS":
                    $where .= " " . $filterdatafield . " LIKE '%" . $filtervalue ."%'";
                    break;
                case "DOES_NOT_CONTAIN":
                    $where .= " " . $filterdatafield . " NOT LIKE '%" . $filtervalue ."%'";
                    break;
                case "GREATER_THAN":
                    $where .= " " . $filterdatafield . " > '" . $filtervalue ."'";
                    break;
                case "LESS_THAN":
                    $where .= " " . $filterdatafield . " < '" . $filtervalue ."'";
                    break;
                case "GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL":
                    $where .= " " . $filterdatafield . " >= '" . $filtervalue ."'";
                    break;
                case "LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL":
                    $where .= " " . $filterdatafield . " <= '" . $filtervalue ."'";
                    break;
            }

            if ($i == $filterscount - 1)
            {
                $where .= ")";
            }

            $tmpfilteroperator = $filteroperator;
            $tmpdatafield = $filterdatafield;
        }
```